# VS Code Intellisense for JavaScript is not working?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm trying to loop over a bunch of buttons to give each of them an event listener that will change the background color once I click any of them, but vs code's IntelliSense won't autocomplete the desired property I'm looking for such .style .

[code snippit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVeII.jpg)

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('btn');

for(let button of buttons) {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        button.*style.backgroundColor* = 'red';
    })
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <section id="container">
        <button class="btn">Click me</button>
        <button class="btn">Click me</button>
        <button class="btn">Click me</button>
        <button class="btn">Click me</button>
    </section>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

VS Code intellisense won't recommend the italicized code .style and .backgroundColor

it's happening of both block and scope level as will as global level.

Comment: `querySelectorAll('btn')` selects all elements like this `<btn></btn>`. Is that what you have in your HTML?

Comment: @LucaKiebel I have 10 buttons with the class of btn.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: my problem is with the autocomplete If I were to type btn.style vs code won't recommend style after I do the dot notation.

Comment: Related: [addEventListener() only gets suggestions for the fullscreenchange and fullscreenerror events on element from document.querySelector. Why?](/q/75329414/11107541)

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/75640206/11107541. I can't close vote because I retracted an earlier cv. can someone help out closing please?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is specified to give you a `NodeList` containing [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) objects, a general base class. Thus each `button` is, as far as the JavaScript IntelliSense can infer, merely an instance of `Element`. But the [`style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) exists on [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement). Therefore you need to 'tell' the IntelliSense engine that `buttons` is going to be a `NodeList` of `HTMLElement` instead, which you can accomplish with a JSDoc:

```
/** @type {NodeListOf<HTMLElement>} */
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('btn');

for(let button of buttons) {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        button.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    })
}
```