# Why is the style property suggested by TypeScript for the result of document.getElementById(), but not document.querySelector()?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

When I write "`document.querySelector().`" and click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to trigger suggestions, the `style` property does not get suggested, but it seems to work fine with `document.getElementById()`.

Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

With `querySelector`:
[image]

With `getElementById`:
[image]

I expected the IntelliSense to suggest the 'style' property with the 'document.querySelector().' but it did not. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>If you're in a hurry and don't care about the "why", skip to the end of this post for the "solution"</sup>

This is interesting. According to the DOM standard, both `querySelector` and `getElementById` return either an `Element` instance, or `null`.

Docs:

- https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-parentnode-queryselector%E2%91%A0
- https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-nonelementparentnode-getelementbyid%E2%91%A1

However, in lib.dom.ts, `querySelector` is typed to return `Element | null`, and `getElementById` for HTML documents is typed to return `HTMLElement | null`. And the `style` DOM property is defined on `HTMLElement`, but not on `Element`.

This was already brought up in the TypeScript GitHub repo's issue tracker here: [`Document.getElementById()` must return `Element`, not `HTMLElement`
#19549](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19549), which was closed to move the discussion of that issue to [Node.parentElement should be Element, not HTMLElement #4689](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4689). You can follow the discussion there. Here are some quotes of the maintainers' thoughts on the matter:

> This is arguable, because there was complainant before saying that it was too cumbersome to always cast the type `Element` to `HTMLElement` when in most common cases the actual type is `HTMLElement`, even though the spec says it should be `Element`.
>
> For example, the return type of `getElementById` is defined as `Element`, however we made it `HTMLElement` to avoid too much casting. If the type is some other `Element`, you can just cast it to `Element` first and then cast it again to the final type. I think in most cases the `parentElement` is `HTMLElement` too, therefore it might be better just leave it the way it is.
>
> - [zhengbli](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4689#issuecomment-146324456)

> @jun-sheaf sent a PR for these changes and I've been reviewing about whether it should make it in for 4.1.
>
> **I don't think we should make these changes**, because it's going to add break a lot of code in a way that people won't think is to their advantage. TS tries to [balance correctness and productivity](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals) and I think making `getElementById` start returning code which needs to be casted to get the same tooling support we have today in the majority of cases (e.g. HTML nodes in a JS context) is going to be a bad call for TypeScript.
>
> [...]
>
> Switching it to `getElementById<E extends Element = HTMLElement>(elementId: string): E | null` on the other hand still allows for setting the return type less drastic ways for the uncommon cases:
>
> ```
> const logo2 = getElementById2("my-logo") as SVGPathElement
> const logo3 = getElementById2<SVGPathElement>("my-logo")
> ```
>
> But doesn't hinder the default JS tooling support.
>
> - [orta](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4689#issuecomment-690503791)

That issue was closed as completed by this commit: [`d561e08`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator/commit/d561e088abd2e8403369ef3609077fb897c0cd74), which basically did what orta was talking about for `getElementById`. I.e. it still returns `HTMLElement` for HTML documents (but not other types of documents like SVG or XML) if I understand correctly.

In other words, things are functioning as the TypeScript maintainers have written them to function.

If you want the `style` property to available on the result of `querySelector`, then type-cast it to an `HTMLElement` using a type assertion (with `as HTMLElement`), or with a JSDoc annotation, or do a runtime type check with `if (foo instanceof HTML...Element) {...}`, or use the generic parameter of `querySelector`.