# Intellisense is not working for elements with a class in querySelectorAll in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, emmet, javascript-intellisense

[please check the problem here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvIJX.png)

In *javscript* When selecting elements with **querySelectorAll()** and adding trying to add them with **.** or a class. Accessing the **node list** elements with index values in that moment *intellisense* don't *work* or *highlight* methods or properties of that **dom element**.

***I want dom properties to appear** in **javascipt** when selecting a **node list elements** Or a element form a list of elements.

Comment: Please directly attach the problem instead of putting the link.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75640206/11107541

Answer (score -1):

Let's try this way, when using querySelectorAll() to select elements and then attempting to access them with dot notation (.) or to access their classes, you may not receive IntelliSense suggestions for the DOM element's properties or methods. This might happen because querySelectorAll() returns a NodeList, which is not an array and doesn't automatically grant access to the properties and methods of DOM elements.

To get full IntelliSense on the DOM elements selected with querySelectorAll(), you can do the following:

Convert the NodeList into an array:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.your-selector');
const elementArray = Array.from(elements);
```

Now, you can access the elements in the array and get full IntelliSense:

```
// Access the first element in the array
const firstElement = elementArray[0];

// Now IntelliSense should suggest properties and methods of the DOM element:
firstElement.textContent = 'New text'; // Example of using a property
firstElement.classList.add('new-class'); // Example of using a method
```

The key is to convert the NodeList into an array so that you can access the elements as if they were array elements and, as a result, receive full IntelliSense. Let me know how with this if it works.

Comment: No it doesn't works .

Comment: Did you use any AI at all in the writing of any part of this answer?